# Minecraft Worlds File

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been using Minecraft Pock Edition through Bluestacks on my PC for quite some time as I thought that was the only way for my son and I to get to play together in a world he had created.

I have since found out this is not the case and would like to move over to the full version through the Microsoft Store.  My question is this...

Is it possible for me to move the world from my PC (created through the bluestacks version) over to this new version through the Microsoft Store?  I can't seem to find the file anywhere on my PC and am wondering if Im just not looking in the correct spot.

Answer (score 1):

Bluestacks is an Android emulator. I'm not sure if it will help you, but maybe the folder path for Android may help. Try navigating to this folder path *inside Bluestacks* (try installing an app like ES File Explorer):

```
/sdcard/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds
```

From there, each folder is one of your worlds. They will have a scrambled name. Enter each folder, look for `levelname.txt` and open it, and you'll see the name of the world. You'll want to get the entire folder.

To move it from BlueStacks to Windows, I think [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/105503) question may help you. The latest versions of Bluestacks have a shared folder at `/sdcard/windows/BstSharedFolder` which you can copy the world folder to. Then you can access the shared folder from your PC at `<BLUESTACKS_DATA>/UserData/SharedFolder`.

Comment: An easier way than checking the level name might just be to look at the world thumbnails